# How can i solve [error: open("venv/bin/python"): Invalid argument fatal: Unable to process path venv/bin/python] this problem?

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv

**I create a django project also create a virtual environment which name is venv after complete my task when i upload this in my github account by github desktop it show fetal error which picture is given below.**

[image: this is my github desktop error pic]

How can i solve this?

Comment: Why do you want to push the virtualenv to git? instead, add the packages list in a requirements.txt and push it to git, you don't have to push the whole env to git

Comment: sorry i try to push all file in my github....... i update my question.

Comment: You don't push *files*. You push *commits*. That's not was the problem here is though: the problem here is that your OS won't let you add the Python executable while you're using it. Exit the Python first. However, as @Sumithran noted, it's a bad idea to commit the venv files in the first place.

Comment: Dear Sir,
i am very sorry for i couldn't understand this because i am a beginner... please kindly describe step step...

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This fetal error is show because it could not found python path in your virtual environment.

So for this first open a .gitignore file in project folder then write virtual environment name in that .gitignore file.

like your virtual environment name venv. 
In the .gitignore file you just write : 
venv/

then save it and problem is solve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).